# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Changed database context to 'DBName'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I am doing a simple connection to SQL database and an ExecuteScalar.

Works fine and returns the scalar value, but looking the execution with Dynatrace, I see that this is throwing internally an exception, in .NET internal classes:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.
Changed database context to 'DBName'.
Changed language setting to us_english.
```

Why is this internal error? How I can avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. Sometimes internal code needlessly throws exceptions; this is one of those cases. These messages are sent as `INFO` tokens on the protocol level, but even a tool like Profiler shows them as "user error messages". They're not actually problematic, the code knows this, but still goes through a path where an exception is constructed for them before recognizing this. With more effort, these "errors" could be wrapped as a separate type and not passed through the exception chain. You can't avoid them unless you fancy building your own version of the framework.

Comment: But this is new in framework 4.0? This don't happens on framework 2.0...

Comment: Sure, why not? It's not like this code is left untouched between releases of the framework. There have been lots of releases of SQL Server and lots of features added since 2.0, which has been out of support for almost 8 years now -- and I can't bother to dig the source from an archive somewhere to check. (To be clear: the informational messages aren't new, just the way they're handled internally.) Ideally, internal code should not throw exceptions just to catch them, but there are very many places where Microsoft's own code is far from ideal.